# Problem with SetComputerName Function

Tags: c, windows, windows-7

I used following line of code to change my computer name:

```
std::string mystr="MY-PC"
bSuccess = SetComputerNameA(mystr.c_str());
if( bSuccess == 0 )
    printf("Unable to change computer name | ERROR %d |", GetLastError());
else
        printf("Name changed successfully");
```

Upon executing the program, 'Name changed successfully' message appeared. Following registry items were found to have the update computer name

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName
>
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName

After restarting my computer, I checked the computer name from **Control Panel\System and Security\System**. To my surprise it still have the old name.

Checked the registry again which contain the new name i.e MY-PC

Any idea why the computer name at **Control Panel\System and Security\System** has not been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SetComputerNameA function only sets the netbios name. You need to use the [SetComputerNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724931%28VS.85%29.aspx) I think.

```
BOOL WINAPI SetComputerNameEx(
  __in  COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT NameType,
  __in  LPCTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

With the `COMPUTER`_NAME_FORMAT as `ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname`