# Rename a Windows Computer / Server with C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to create a Configuration Tool for new devices, which has to be set up.

That's why I am trying to set the local hostname with a Button.

I want to use the name which I wrote in a textbox

```
public void SetMachineName(string newName)
    {

        // Create a new process
        ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();

        // set name of process to "WMIC.exe"
        process.FileName = "WMIC.exe";

        // pass rename PC command as argument
        process.Arguments = "computersystem where caption='" + System.Environment.MachineName + "' rename " + newName;

        // Run the external process & wait for it to finish
        using (Process proc = Process.Start(process))
        {
            proc.WaitForExit();

            // print the status of command
            Console.WriteLine("Exit code = " + proc.ExitCode);
        }
    }

    public void Click_sethostname(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetMachineName(Textbox_sethostname.Text);
    }
```

[WPF setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpPsd.png)

I have following namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Did you run your program "Run as administrator" ?

Comment: My question is how i can change it so it does work.

Yeah i run my Program with "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with SetComputerName Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650635/problem-with-setcomputername-function)